# Getting an error with Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:2)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to add a competition to my firebase with uploading and image but I get this error, "Getting an error with Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:2)" and in my terminal it says "[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ref]". Does anyone have any ideas about what's happening?

When I try to display my user's name it also shows the same error...

Below is my code for my Database.js file where I do the main functionality to upload to firebase.

```
import { auth, db } from "./firebase";
import  {doc, setDoc, Timestamp, collection, getDoc, getDocs,addDoc, onSnapshot} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { async, querystring } from '@firebase/util';


export const createUserOnRegister = (user, username) => {

    const userRef = doc(db, 'avatars', user.uid);

    const userData = {
        email: user.email,
        username: username,
        uid: user.uid,
        role: 'student',
        dateCreated: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    }

    return setDoc(userRef, userData);
}

export const getAvatar = async () => {

    const userRef = doc(db, "avatars", auth.currentUser.uid);
    const snap = await getDoc(userRef);

  
    let avatar = {...doc.data(), uid: doc.id}
    avatars.push(avatar);

}

export const updateProfile = (uid, data) => {
    const userRef = doc(db, 'avatars', uid)
    return setDoc(userRef, data, {merge: true}) 
}

export const newComp = (comp) => {
    return addDoc( collection(db, 'comps'), comp )
}

export const getAllComp = () => {
    return collection(db, "comps");
}

export const getEntryOffComp = async(id) => {
    let entries = []

    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'comps/' + id + '/entries')
    const collectionSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'entries'))

    collectionSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        entries.push(doc.data());
    })

    return entries

}

export const addEntryToComp = (data, id) => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'comp/' + id + '/entries')

    return addDoc(collectionRef, data)
}
```

Comment: Your code has no variable `ref`, so the cause for the error must be in code you have not shared.

Comment: But I don't use 'ref' anywhere else in my code. I spotlight searched and it's only available in Database.js file.